# X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-headers, x-frame-options

With "X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM" how can i allow one domain but with http and https requests?

I have the header below but the client also server the site in http://www.example.com.

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://www.example.com
```

Comment: Note ALLOW-FROM isn't supported in Chrome. This is a dealbreaker for most sites. You may want to use CSP frame-ancestors which is supported everywhere except IE and Edge.

Comment: True @StefanOS but for chrome i use Content-Security-Policy header

Comment: Ok. Just for the record, Chrome gives preference to X-Frame-Options over content security policy. So you need to serve different headers based on the user agent.

Comment: @StefanOS i can't find information about that precedence between X-Frame-Options and Content-Security-Policy in webkit browsers. I send both headers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like there's no option for allowing both HTTP and HTTPS schemes within the same ALLOW-FROM header. Quoting from [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034).

> As the "ALLOW-FROM" field only supports one serialized-origin, in
> cases when the server wishes to allow more than one resource to frame
> its content, the following design pattern can fulfill that need:
>
> 1. A page that wants to render the requested content in a frame
>    supplies its own origin information to the server providing the
>    content to be framed via a query string parameter.
> 2. The server verifies that the hostname meets its criteria, so that
>    the page is allowed to be framed by the target resource.  This
>    may, for example, happen via a lookup of a whitelist of trusted
>    domain names that are allowed to frame the page.  For example,
>    for a Facebook "Like" button, the server can check to see that
>    the supplied hostname matches the hostname(s) expected for that
>    "Like" button.
> 3. The server returns the hostname in "X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM"
>    if the proper criteria was met in step #2.
> 4. The browser enforces the "X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM" header.